# String Comparisons - C

Tags: c, pointers, string

I'm trying to write a string routine in C, and I keep hitting on the same issue.

In C, I have this string:

```
MAMAAMAAALJ
```

If I have this string:

```
AAA
```

How can I determine that AAA is inside of MAMAAMAAAJ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many `C` runtime libraries contain the function [strstr (const char *s1, const char *s2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strstr).

If s2 is within s1, it returns a pointer within s1 to the beginning of the substring, otherwise returns NULL.

Comment: *All* conforming hosted implementations of C provide `strstr`.

Comment: How many `C` implementations are conforming?  In my experience, a few have some other name for this function and a few don't offer anything too close to it.

Comment: I think pretty much every general-purpose C compiler supports `strstr`. Many environments also include the POSIX standard `index` function in `<strings.h>`, but ANSI C is certainly more widespread.

Answer (score 1):

```
strstr("MAMAAMAAAJ", "AAA");
```

returns the pointer to the occurrence of the search string, or NULL if not found

Answer (score 1):

Boyer–Moore string search algorithm

---

[C realization](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html)

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote or downvote, so I will not vote.

Comment: BM for very short string, im in same situasion as stefan.